# Step gives error sound but not description

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to run some code on Visual basic and about an hour ago it was working fine. I did something(not sure what) and now it gives an error sound but no description. This only happens when I try to create my own function in a module.

I have tried turning my pc on then off. I have opened different excel spreadsheets and yet it still won't let me run my function even with steps. My code below is incomplete but I'm sure it isn't the code itself thats the problem.

```
Function onetube(Thi As Double, Tho As Double, Tci As Double, Tco As Double) As Double

Dim phih, phic, phicf As Double
Dim ai(1 To 4, 1 To 4) As Variant

phih = (Thi - Tho) / (Thi - Tci)
phic = (Tco - Tci) / (Thi - Tci)
phicf = (phih - phic) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln((1 - phic) / (1 - phih))

ai(1, 1) = -0.462
ai(1, 2) = -0.0313
ai(1, 3) = -0.174
ai(1, 4) = -0.042
ai(2, 1) = 5.08
ai(2, 2) = 0.529
ai(2, 3) = 1.32
ai(2, 4) = 0.347
ai(3, 1) = -15.7
ai(3, 2) = -2.37
ai(3, 3) = -2.93
ai(3, 4) = -0.853
ai(4, 1) = 17.2
ai(4, 2) = 3.18
ai(4, 3) = 1.99
ai(4, 4) = 0.649

onetube = phicf

End Function
```

Comment: `onetube = Phi`. What is `Phi`? You don't declare or use it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry that was originally onetube = phicf. I corrected it now but still gives the same error noise.

Comment: Please share what the values of `Thi`, `Tho`, `Tci` and `Tco` are when you are calling this function. What is `ai` used for too?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code itself it still gives me an error when I do a basic function like x+y. I think I may be a setting or something.

Comment: Then I'm not sure we can help to be honest. I don't know how to replicate the problem you are having. Maybe uninstall and reinstall Excel?

Comment: it's worth a try. I'll post again after I've tried

Comment: @JonoArmstrong You need to give an example of sample input - the input might be formatted incorrectly, like as text.

Comment: An easy way to localize these kind of desperate errors is the "code halving method": comment out half of the code and see what happens. If the problem persists, continue halving the rest. Sometimes it helps  simply changing the name of the function. Good luck :) Another advice: make sure you do not divide by zero, also make sure `phic < 1`.

Comment: If something is "pinging" I'd say there's a "block" somewhere. If stopping and restarting Excel doesn't work, try rebooting Windows...